# Creating an application which takes in user numbers

Tags: android

I am trying to receive user input in the application, representing numbers from a lottery ticket, which can then be compared with numbers from the website. I have used JSoup library to parse the numbers from the website but I am struggling with receiving user input into the app. I have used EditText object to allow the user to enter their numbers but currently my app is only displaying the results of the user input. I would like to know how to receive the input that can then be compared with the lottery numbers. Can anyone please help.

My code is below:

```
public class StartingPoint extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = ".com.spc.checklotterynumbers.MESSAGE";
    final Context context = this;
    private EditText edittext;
    int lotteryNumbers;
    Button check;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);



    }//onCreate

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
        return true;
    }//onCreateOptionsMenu

    /**Called when the user clicks the send button*/
    public void checkNumbers(View view) {
        //Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);



    }//checkNumbers



    public static void main (String [] args){

        //link to the intended web site 
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.national-lottery.co.uk/player/p/drawHistory.do").get();

            Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("drawhistory");
            Element table = elements.first();
            Element tbody = table.getElementsByTag("tbody").first();

            Element firstLottoRow = tbody.getElementsByClass("lottorow").first();

            Element dateElement = firstLottoRow.child(0);
            System.out.println(dateElement.text());

            Element gameElement = firstLottoRow.child(1);
            System.out.println(gameElement.text());

            Element noElement = firstLottoRow.child(2);
            System.out.println(noElement.text());

            String [] split = noElement.text().split(" - ");
            // set up an array to store numbers from the latest draw on the lottery web page
            Integer [] numbers = new Integer [split.length];

            int i = 0;
            for (String strNo : split) {
                numbers [i] = Integer.valueOf(strNo);
                i++;
            }

            for (Integer no : numbers) { 
                System.out.println(no);
            }

            Element bonusElement = firstLottoRow.child(3);
            Integer bonusBall = Integer.valueOf(bonusElement.text());
            System.out.println("Bonus ball: " + bonusBall);
            //Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementsByTag("main-article-content");




        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: there is no main in android

Comment: This is all your code? Where is the listener to SEND button?

Comment: I used a tutorial that set up this screen of displaying a message but didnt use a listener for the send button. I thought this checkNumbers method substituted this?